# Does the Bible prohibit wearing face masks in public?

Tags: prophecy, ezekiel, commandments

The command to "**cover not thy lips**" essentially appears twice in the following passage of Ezekiel. Should this be understood as a prohibition against wearing face masks in public, and if so does it continue beyond the time of Ezekiel?

*[Ezekiel 24:15-27 quoted for context]*

> Also the word of the LORD came unto me, saying, 24:15
>
> Son of man, behold, I take away from thee the desire of thine eyes
> with a stroke: yet neither shalt thou mourn nor weep, neither shall
> thy tears run down. 24:16
>
> Forbear to cry, make no mourning for the dead, bind the tire of thine
> head upon thee, and put on thy shoes upon thy feet, **and cover not
> thy lips,** and eat not the bread of men. 24:17
>
> So I spake unto the people in the morning: and at even my wife died;
> and I did in the morning as I was commanded. 24:18
>
> And the people said unto me, Wilt thou not tell us what these things
> are to us, that thou doest so? 24:19
>
> Then I answered them, The word of the LORD came unto me, saying, 24:20
>
> Speak unto the house of Israel, Thus saith the Lord GOD; Behold, I
> will profane my sanctuary, the excellency of your strength, the desire
> of your eyes, and that which your soul pitieth; and your sons and your
> daughters whom ye have left shall fall by the sword. 24:21
>
> And ye shall do as I have done: **ye shall not cover your lips,** nor
> eat the bread of men. 24:22
>
> And your tires shall be upon your heads, and your shoes upon your
> feet: ye shall not mourn nor weep; but ye shall pine away for your
> iniquities, and mourn one toward another. 24:23
>
> Thus Ezekiel is unto you a sign: according to all that he hath done
> shall ye do: and when this cometh, ye shall know that I am the Lord
> GOD. 24:24
>
> Also, thou son of man, shall it not be in the day when I take from
> them their strength, the joy of their glory, the desire of their eyes,
> and that whereupon they set their minds, their sons and their
> daughters, 24:25
>
> That he that escapeth in that day shall come unto thee, to cause thee
> to hear it with thine ears? 24:26
>
> In that day shall thy mouth be opened to him which is escaped, and
> thou shalt speak, and be no more dumb: and thou shalt be a sign unto
> them; and they shall know that I am the LORD. 24:27

Certainly, a face mask covers the lips. Does Ezekiel 24 prohibit wearing face masks?

Comment: (-1) This question makes very little sense - are you suggesting that verse is also prohibiting people from crying, mourning, or eating bread? Why would God's interactions with Ezekiel have anything to do with restrictions for anybody else?

Comment: @SteveTaylor  Why would God's interactions with anyone have anything to do with anyone else?  This question is a legitimate question.  Perhaps your comment could be converted into an answer as you seem to be sure of your understanding.

Comment: @SteveTaylor  Well, it's my first time to ask anything here, so perhaps I don't understand something about the fine print.  Can you adjust the wording and reopen it so that it "fits"?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I saw the 706 rep but hadn't appreciated this was your first question. The site guidance around questions is rather specific, so all of us tend to have some of our early questions closed and need to rework them somewhat. So don't worry, it's not just you! I can edit your question to fit the site guidance, but my first Comment still stands - if it's a restriction on face masks then it would be a restriction on eating bread, which wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: By the way, what is the purpose of hermeneutics if none of the Bible is supposed to have a present-day application and/or we're not supposed to talk about it?

Comment: @Polyhat I agree with your comment. If we are asking for an understanding of part of a text, even if trying to relate it to a current world context, how can that be offtopic? Otherwise, what is the point of any of this? I have upvoted the question...it deserves an answer because any biblical passage that can shed light on life is important. This one definately has merit...even though I personally do not agree that what is written in Ezekiel has anything to do with wearing or not wearing face masks under COVID (or any disease outbreak).

Comment: The key thing is that hermeneutics is about *exegesis* - understanding the text in its own intended context, first and foremost. In the [On Topic](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section we state: *"Questions are on topic if they are focused on the text, rather than things to which the text may apply."* Essentially, the guideline is that Questions should stay focused on interpreting the text in its own context, but Answers may opt to provide application.

Comment: We all carry our own baggage and biases to the text, and if we bring that with us into the interpretation process, it risks skewing our reasoning. In terms of exegetical process, the best place to start is by asking what the text means in its own context, and why. I suspect that if you answer that for this text, you will have a very clear answer to your more general query.

Comment: The issue i have with that statement is that it forces one to accept answers that may actually not address the original O.P's reason for posting. Not everyone read texts in the same way and certainly, we all take different things out of them. For example, I worship on the Seventh Day Sabbath because the 10 commandments tell me i should. Do you? If not, why not? see my point. I am assuming he would have to post this on Christianity then?

Comment: If anyone has a conscience about wearing a mask (or a health reason for that matter) then they can wear a face shield. They are actually more comfortable, in my view.

Comment: If you want to, you can also ask us whether having open heart surgery is what Moses had in mind when he penned Deuteronomy (10:16), and whether **(a)** it "still" applies to Jews or Christians today, and **(b)** it might help explain why there are so many successful Jewish surgeons. :-\

Comment: @Lucian This was a different question before it was closed, then edited to make it "correct".  Apparently, the question I wanted to ask _cannot_ be asked here.  I did address surgeons in that original question.

Comment: @Polyhat: Every version of this question, past and present, appears nonsensical, and the fact that a human being actually felt the need to even ask it in the first place seems equally disturbing.

Answer (score 5):

Matthew Poole correctly observes -

> **Cover not thy lips**: it was a custom among them to cover either the upper lip, or mustaches, as the leper did, Leviticus 13:45, and as
> Micah 3:7; and this also is forbidden the prophet.

Thus, covering the lips was simply one of the funeral rituals/customs when morning the dead.

This ancient Hebrew practice had nothing whatever to do with the imperative to cover the face with a protective mask for the sanitary purposes or others.

Comment: Good points: +1. It great to hear that the inside of everyone's masks is "sanitary" :-)